# Combining two items (recipe-like)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'd like a user to be able to combine two items and if compatible will yield a new item. In this example, the item IDs will be saved as Strings.

I was wondering what the most efficient way to do this would be, while making sure that swapped order will always yield the same result, so the user could input the order:

```
item X + item Y = item Z
item Y + item X = item Z
```

I've tried using Dictionaries and Objects, but I just haven't been able to get anything to work. I've also tried some various libraries that include HashMap/HashSet but nothing is working. here's some pseduo-code:

```
itemRecipe1:HashSet = new HashSet();
itemRecipe1.add("2");//Add item with ID of 2
itemRecipe1.add("3");//Add item with ID of 3

inputRecipe:HashSet = new HashSet();
inputRecipe.add("3");//Add item with ID of 3 (swapped)
inputRecipe.add("2");//Add item with ID of 2 (swapped)

recipeList:HashMap = new HashMap();
receipeList.put(itemRecipe1, "11");//Recipe has been added, the result of the recipe should be item 11

//This should output as TRUE since the composition of itemRecipe1 and inputRecipe are the same, despite a different input order.
trace(receipeList.containsKey(inputRecipe));
```

If anyone has a solution for this issue, please elt me know as I am willing to implement any design I can get working. I just don't see how a Dictionary could work as the key order matters.

Comment: It's hard to know what the rules are for combining elements. Is this for replicating some basic chemistry reactions or some imaginary wizardry potion creation system for a game ? Either way you need to have a clear set of rules, then it will be easier to make the associations. One thing that comes to mind is bytes and using binary arithmetic.

Comment: More like the "wizardry potion system" but with only two items. I want to compare two objects and if that value pair is found, then get the key value. My only issue is that I want the two keys to have interchangeable order, yielding the same key value. "2" & "3" = "11" and "3" & "2" = "11".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're trying to associate two or more objects with each other. The first thing you need is some primitive data you can use to represent each item uniquely, typically an ID. This should give you something like the following to begin with:

```
class Item {
    public var _id:int;

    public function Item(id:int) {
        _id = id;
    }

    public function get id():int { return _id; }
}
```

Now you need some piece of data that establishes a relationship between multiple Items using this ID. That could be as simple as the following, with a little extra functionality thrown in to see if an input list of these IDs matches the relationship:

```
class ItemRelationship {
    private var _items:Vector.<Item>;

    public function ItemRelationship(items:Vector.<Item>) {
        _items = items;
    }

    public function matches(ids:Vector.<int>):Boolean {
        if (_items.length !== ids.length) {
            return false;
        }

        for each (var item:Item in _items) {
            var found:Boolean = false;

            for each (var id:int in ids) {
                if (item.id === id) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!found) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function get items():Vector.<Item> { return _items; }
}
```

This lets us do something like this, assuming we have a bunch of items (`item1`, `item2`, ...) with IDs.

```
var rel:ItemRelationship = new ItemRelationship(new <Item>[item1, item2]);
```

And then:

```
trace(rel.matches(new <int>[1,2])); // true
trace(rel.matches(new <int>[2,1])); // true
trace(rel.matches(new <int>[3,4])); // false
```

Now all we need is something that stores all of these relationships and lets us fetch one based on a list of input IDs:

```
class RelationshipCollection {
    private var _relationships:Vector.<ItemRelationship>;

    public function RelationshipCollection(relationships:Vector.<ItemRelationship>) {
        _relationships = relationships;
    }

    public function find(ids:Vector.<int>):ItemRelationship {
        for each(var relationship:ItemRelationship in _relationships) {
            if (relationship.matches(ids)) return relationship;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Put a load of relationships in there:

```
var collection:RelationshipCollection = new RelationshipCollection(new <ItemRelationship>[
    new ItemRelationship(new <Item>[item1, item4]),
    new ItemRelationship(new <Item>[item2, item3])
]);
```

And give it a whirl:

```
trace(collection.find(new <int>[1, 3])); // null (no match)
trace(collection.find(new <int>[1, 4])); // works
trace(collection.find(new <int>[3, 2])); // works
trace(collection.find(new <int>[2, 3])); // works
```

Of course for the sake of readability you can rename each class to something more appropriate for its application e.g. `Item => Potion`, `ItemRelationship => Recipe`, `RelationshipCollection => RecipeBook`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! What would I need to do to assign the two values sets a value, though? A user will offer two items and, if found in the collection, result in a combination item.

ex.) item1 (apple) and item4 (caramel), if found in the collection, should contain the value item9 (caramel apple).

Comment: @dinorider You mean you want a a recipe to only contain one item which is a "combination" of the inserted items? I think a tidier way to do that would be to add a new method to `ItemRelationship` which produces something like `caramelapple` based on its contents e.g. `getCombinedItem()`. Does that sound like what you are trying to do? This way you don't lose the current functionality or ability to be able to access the individual items / ingredients as well.

Comment: Ideally, my end result would be setting up the recipes like this:
var CaramelApple:ItemRelationship = new ItemRelationship(new <Item>[new Item(1),new Item(4)]); --- From there, I'd like to be able to add it to a sort of recipeBook which has the ingredient value, like this: recipeBook.add(CaramelApple, new Item(9)); --- This way, I could easily just check to see if a recipe exists in the recipe book, and if it does, get the resulting recipe, via something like: if(recipeBook.contains(CaramelApple)) { recipeBook.getRecipe(CaramelApple) };

Comment: @dinorider I think what I have here sort of supports what you're trying to do. If you expand my code to have an `add` method to push things into `_relationships` and then create your `contains` method [which could look something like this](https://gist.github.com/MartyWallace/20e6bb3bd15d1c4afa04), that should cover most of what you've asked about. The only confusion I have is where you've used `add` to add both a "recipe" (CaramelApple) *and* a single Item.

Comment: My intention is that the CaramelApple recipe (item1 and item4) are assigned to create a new item in the recipeBook (item9). So if the user submits item1 and item4 as ingredients, the recipeBook will find those two ingredients are indeed and pair and it will retrieve the recipe result (item9).

Comment: Using a `pop` and `push`, I found a way to modify the `find` function to accept an additional parameter, which then spits out the resulting recipe, setup like: caramelApple = new ItemRelationship(new <Item>[new Item(2), new Item(3), new Item(9)]). It searches only the first two array values and then spits out the 3rd element if it finds the first two. In this way, `collection.find(new <int>[3, 2]);` returns the value "9". Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Oh cool no worries I'm glad you finally got where you were trying to go :-)

Answer (score 0):

> so the user could input the order

The first step is to limit the possible input. If you allow any type of input, you have to parse that input and things get complicated very quickly.

Create an input method that only allows the user to put two items together, say for example via drag and drop of the items to only 2 slots.

> I just don't see how a Dictionary could work as the key order matters.

The important part is to design the keys well.

As [@George Profenza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89766/george-profenza) pointed out in the comments, you could change your IDs to a different format. Instead of having `1, 2, 3, ... n` you could use `1, 2, 4, ... 2^n`. The advantage is that you can combine any two IDs uniquely via bitwise *or* operator (|). In the following example, two such IDs are combined (binary notation):

```
  00001
| 10000
--------
  10001
```

As you can see, each ID occupies a separate position in binary:  the 1st position and the 5th. Combining both via *or* operator means that now both 1st and 5th position are 1. The order doesn't matter. If you use such IDs in the form of powers of 2 you can combine them regardless of the order to form pairs, which can then be used as keys to a dictionary.

---

Another solution is to simply sort the pair of IDs.

The combination 3-2 becomes 2-3 and the combination 2-3 stays 2-3. Both 2-3 and 3-2 lead to the same result.

You can then build your data structure accordingly, that is: the outer data structure is for the lower ID number and the nested, inner one is for the bigger ID number. Here's some pseudo code with generic objects:

```
var map:Object = {};
map["2"] = {"3":"combination 2-3"};
```

To access that, you'd do something like:

```
trace(map[Math.min(ID1, ID2)][Math.max(ID1, ID2)])
```

---

There's also the brute force way of doing it by storing both possible combinations in the data structure. The code for that could roughly look like that:

```
var map:Object = {};
map["2"] = {"3":"combination 2-3"};
map["3"] = {"2":"combination 2-3"};
```

Now both

```
trace(map[ID1][ID2]);
```

and

```
trace(map[ID2][ID1]);
```

Should yield the same result.